# Swift. How to declare func with return type from imported library in protocol?

Tags: ios, swift, import, protocols

I use many libraries in my proj with cocoapods. It requires importing this libraries into files where I uses instances of classes from it.

Today I decide to create protocol and one of declared func must return type from imported library:

```
import SwiftyJSON

protocol ContainsProductsList {
    func productsSummaryPrice() -> Int
    func productsCount() -> Int
    func productsAvailability(date : String) -> Calendar.Availability
    func JSON() -> JSON
}
```

but compiler don't allow me to do this (Use undeclared type 'JSON'). I tried to place protocol in another file which use SwiftyJSON lib, but result was same. Could you explain why this happens? Maybe there is a way to bypass this?

Comment: Have you tried declaring this function in a class (not protocol) and if so what are the results? Have you imported everything correctly? Are you using the `use_frameworks!` header in the pod file (which you must for swift).

Answer (score 2):

Use proper naming of the method:

```
protocol ContainsProductsList {
    func productsSummaryPrice() -> Int
    func productsCount() -> Int
    func productsAvailability(date : String) -> Calendar.Availability
    func JSONMYFUNCTION() -> JSON
}
```

Comment: correct)) I renamed the func and compiler keep calm. Probably it decide that func name (JSON()) is new JSON object instance. Thanks a lot